# What is the translation of engelmannii?

Tags: translation-check, latin-to-english-translation

I see this latin word used in many botany names as the species name, of genus-species.
Google translate said 'National Forest'. I'm skeptical.

What is the translation to English of engelmannii?

Ophioglossum engelmannii,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means Engelmann's, using the Latinized form of that name, *Engelmannius*. Engelmann is a common German surname, but the likely namesake of the plants you encountered is [Georg Engelmann](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Engelmann), a prolific German-American botanist.

Google Translate shines as usual.

Comment: Today, the Wikipedia page you link says: "He is commemorated in the names of several plants, including [Engelmann Oak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quercus_engelmannii) (_Quercus engelmannii_), [Engelmann Spruce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engelmann_Spruce) (_Picea engelmannii_), [Apache Pine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Pine) (_Pinus engelmannii_), [Engelmann's quillwort or Appalachian quillwort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoetes_engelmannii) (_Isoetes engelmannii_), and [Engelmann's Prickly-pear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opuntia_engelmannii) (_Opuntia engelmannii_)."

Comment: +1. I was thinking of writing an answer to say basically the same, before yours arrived. I'd only add that: 1) it is common practice in biological Latin for species naming to honor important naturalists this way, and 2) unlike everywhere else, in biology it is _always_ accepted to regularly Latinize names (especially last names) by appending -us or -ius. (This gives place to strange cases of Romance names irregularly Latinized, like [Chelonoidis niger donfaustoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelonoidis_niger_donfaustoi) instead of, say, C. n. domnifausti.)